Geometric computation crashes - version or code related?
Currently I am doing a little geometric computation that consists of
a) choosing a random rotated rectangle inside a larger rectangle and
b) then compute a cover of this inside rectangle by other rectangles
chosen in a random way.
I put the code in the file compcover.ml which reads
regwh[reg_] := Module[{r, p1, p2}, 
  r = List @@ BoundingRegion[reg];
  p1 = r[[1]];
  p2 = r[[2]];
  p2 - p1
  ]

showExample[res_, n_] := Graphics[{Blue, res[[1]], Gray, res[[2]]}]

showExample[res_] := showExample[res, 1]

prepareExample[w_, h_, w1_, h1_] :=
 Module[{outerRect, innerRect, d1, phi, w2, h2, p, qrRect},
  outerRect = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {w, h}];
  d1 = 1/2 Sqrt[w1^2 + h1^2] + 20;
  phi = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}];
  w2 = w - 2 d1;
  h2 =  h - 2 d1;
  innerRect = RegionResize[outerRect, {w2, h2}];
  p = RandomPoint[innerRect];
  qrRect = TransformedRegion[Rectangle[{-w1/2, -h1/2  }, {w1/2, h1/2}],
    RotationTransform[phi]];
  qrRect = TransformedRegion[qrRect, TranslationTransform[p]];
  {outerRect, qrRect}
  ]


prepareExample[r1_Rectangle, w1_, h1_] := Module[{pc, wh, res, r2a},
  pc = RegionCentroid[r1];
  wh = regwh[r1];
  res = prepareExample[wh[[1]], wh[[2]], w1, h1];
  r2a = TransformedRegion[res[[2]], TranslationTransform[pc - wh/2]];
  {r1, r2a}
  
  ]


genOverlap[res_, a_] :=
Module[
    {r1, r2, 
    rAkt, r2Aux,
    wh2, whmin, wh1,
    reslis,
    dyTop, dxRight, yTop, xRight, yBottom, xLeft,
    pAkt},

    r1 = res[[1]];
    r2 = res[[2]];
    

    wh1 = regwh[r1];
    wh2 = regwh[r2];

    whmin = Min[wh2];

    reslis = {};

    rAkt = r2;

    Until[rAkt == EmptyRegion[2],

        pAkt = RandomPoint[rAkt];
                
        dyTop = wh1[[2]] - pAkt[[2]];
        dxRight = wh1[[1]] - pAkt[[1]];

        yTop = pAkt[[2]] + Min[dyTop/2, a whmin/2];
        xRight = pAkt[[1]] + Min[dxRight/2, a whmin/2];

        yBottom = Max[pAkt[[2]]/2, pAkt[[2]] - a whmin/2];
        xLeft = Max[pAkt[[1]]/2, pAkt[[1]] - a whmin/2];


        r2Aux = Rectangle[{xLeft, yBottom}, {xRight, yTop}];

        rAkt = RegionDifference[rAkt, r2Aux];
        
                
        reslis = Append[reslis, r2Aux];
    ];
    reslis
]


tst[a_] := Module[{res, reslis}, 
  res = prepareExample[1500, 1100, 500, 300];
  reslis = genOverlap[res, a];
  {Length[reslis], 
   Graphics[{{Opacity[0.2], Blue, res[[1]], Red, 
      res[[2]]}, {RandomColor[], Opacity[0.2], #} & /@ reslis}]}
  ]


tst1[a_] := Module[{res, reslis}, 
  res = prepareExample[1500, 1100, 500, 300];
  reslis = genOverlap[res, a];
  reslis   
  ]

I then prepared a notebook which contains essentially the commands
Import["compcover.ml"]
Table[tst[1.0][[1]],20]
In my installation of Mathematica (13.2, Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS, HPZ240) the second line almost certainly crashes - everything in the notebook gets undefined and one can/must start afresh.
I am not sure if there is a bug in my code and so I executed the code via .NET/Link and WolframEngine 14.1 on a Windows 10 Notebook. There the Table seemingly always gets built. So is it a version problem? Or a problem of the old Ubuntu version?
Maybe someone could give the code a try on a newer Ubuntu/Mathematica version.

Went fine for me in Mathematica 14.1 on macos 14.7.1 on Apple Silicon (arm64).

Work fine in version 14.1 on Windows 11  but crash in version 13.3.1 on Windows 11.

Crash in version 14.0 on Windows 10.

Version, not code.
